# Autoencoder for sentence embeddings with high loss

Tags: text, pytorch, nlp, lstm, autoencoder

I'm trying to construct an autoencoder for sentence embeddings. Below the architecture:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pack_padded_sequence


class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 vocab_dim: int,
                 embedding_dim: int,
                 hidden_dim: int,
                 proj_dim: int,
                 num_layers: int = 1,
                 dropout: float = 0.0,
                 tune_embeddings: bool = True):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()

        self.context_size = 10

        self.embedder = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=vocab_dim, embedding_dim=embedding_dim, padding_idx=0)
        self.embedder.weight.requires_grad = tune_embeddings

        self.encoder = nn.GRU(embedding_dim * self.context_size,
                              hidden_dim,
                              num_layers=num_layers,
                              dropout=dropout,
                              bidirectional=False,
                              batch_first=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        lengths = torch.sum(x != 0, dim=1)
        embeds = self.embedder(x.long())
        embeds = embeds.unfold(1, self.context_size, 1)
        embeds = embeds.contiguous().view(embeds.size(0), embeds.size(1), -1)
        # packing variable length sequence is required, otherwise LSTM will run the over the non-required padded words
        packed_data = pack_padded_sequence(embeds,
                                           [x - self.context_size + 1 for x in lengths],
                                           batch_first=True,
                                           enforce_sorted=False)
        output, hidden = self.encoder(packed_data)
        return hidden


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 vocab_dim: int,
                 embedding_dim: int,
                 hidden_dim: int,
                 output_dim: int,
                 num_layers: int = 1,
                 dropout: float = 0.0):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()

        self.decoder = nn.GRU(1, hidden_dim, num_layers=num_layers, batch_first=True, dropout=dropout, bidirectional=False)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

        self.output_dim = output_dim

    def forward(self, x, hidden, teacher_forcing: bool = True):
        batch_size = x.size(0)
        seq_len = x.size(1)
        output = torch.zeros(seq_len, batch_size, self.output_dim).to(x.device)

        input_dec = torch.full((batch_size, 1, 1), 2, dtype=torch.float)  # start of sentence
        t = 0
        while t < seq_len:
            output_step, hidden = self.decoder(input_dec, hidden[-1].unsqueeze(0))
            output[t] = self.fc(output_step.squeeze(1))

            if teacher_forcing:
                input_dec = x[:, t][:, None, None].long()  # Use ground truth as the next input_dec
            else:
                input_dec = output_step.long()  # Use the model's prediction as the next input_dec

            if input_dec[:, t].any() == 0:
                break
            t += 1
        return output.transpose(0, 1)
```

the goal is to reconstruct the input sentences therefore I'm using MSE Loss as loss and autoregression/teacher forcing inside the decoder. However, the model is not learning.
The sentences are encoded into a simple word to index manner, I've preprocessed the dataset removing digits, exceeding white spaces and so on..

I'm a beginner, can someone give some advices?